# Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException Target class [HotelSeeder] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-seeding

I am trying to use seeder following a tutorial but I am always getting this error

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException

Target class [HotelSeeder] does not exist.
```

when I run this command :

```
php artisan db:seed
```

I have in database\seeders\DatabaseSeeder.php
add this line

```
$this->call(\HotelSeeder::class);
```

into the up function

and in database\seeders\HotelSeeder.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class HotelSeeder extends Seeder
{
```

**I am using latest version laravel 8 and phpstorm **

I have tried lot of solutions like composer dump-autoload and adding namespace to the seeder function but none of them has worked.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Well I have found the solution:
I have launched

```
composer dumpautoload
```

then I have gone to package.json and added this line

```
"classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
```

Before :

```
},
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
```

After

```
    },
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
```

and I have rerun

```
composer dumpautoload
```

and It works !